# power bank paired with a mouse system

Tags: power-supply, pcb, circuit-analysis, electricity, mouse

I would like in a class project to couple a PowerBank and a mouse.

Imagine a powerbank in a parallel circuit with a mouse in such a way that one can charge his phone with it and recharge the powerbank while using it as a mouse.

That's my idea.

My question is how do I go about it ? Any suggestion guys ?

Thanks for sharing.

Comment: You cannot do this in general. It would only be possible on phones which support an atypical charging-while-host mode, with the details depending on the way this is implemented on a particular device.  Such questions are too dependent on unspecified details of finished consumer products, and too short on engineering specifics to be a fit here.  **Likely you should pick a more reasonable project.**

Comment: Ya, it's true it's not specific enough. But it's because I am a rookie. I still expected some insight out of it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you need a phone that supports Usb OTG as well as charging at the same time. These do exist.

A practical compromise would be using a Bluetooth mouse. Using the Bluetooth would  allow you to use the power bank as a mouse, power the Bluetooth circuit from its battery, and still plug in as a power bank. So the usb is only for power.

Comment: Dude, the Bluetooth idea is brilliant!